# Problem with PDF format in Crystal Report

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

One of my friend suggested me to use this site in order to find an answer my question that struggle to overcome.

I am using visual studio 2008 and I am preparing reports for some forms, and I wanna print this document as PDF format. I am opening my report as PDF format but when I open as PDF format my report has page break every one written page.

I do not know what the problem is, so Is there anyone who can help me about this situation.

I will be waiting the answers

Thank you

Comment: Can you upload this document somewhere for us to check out? It's kind of hard to know what you mean at this point.

Comment: I am sorry that I couldnn't explain goodly what my problem is. 

I am sorry that I cannot download this document because it is forbidden.

My problem is that when I see my design for report there is no any page break or any blank, but when I wanna take my report as PDF format, it is doing like this;

one page there is something that is written, and then one page "page break" and then again and again. 
My report should be 6 pages but because of these page breaks my report gets 12 pages. And the crystal report put this page break automatically,so how can I overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You might also check the setting of the "keep object together" at the following levels: field/item, section, group section (e.g., Details for an item in "Details c") and sub-report.  I have solved some extra pagebreaks by unchecking these.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 possibilities:
1. You may have some objects on the right side of your report that are spilling over into a horizontal page.  Look at all of your images,text boxes, etc. and move them a little to the left.

For example, I often put my company logo on the upper right side of my reports. But sometimes I move it a little *too* far right and Crystal compensates by adding a second horizontal page to contain the rest of the image.  Easily fixed by moving the logo left.

2. Look at the properties for each of your report sections. These properties include "page break before" and "page break after".  Try unchecking these boxes and see if the problem still exists.